# Soft Question about Lipschitz functions: $\inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\{u(y) + td(x,y) \}$

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, proof-explanation

I'm reading a proof about approximating lower semicontinuous functions by lipschitz functions. Commonly I read the formula:

$$u_t(x) = \inf_{y \in \mathbb{R}}\{u(y) + td(x,y) \}$$

I'm having trouble understanding what this function "looks like." For instance, if $u(y) = y^2$, if we want to compute $u_t(1)$, it appears that choosing $y=x=1$ will infimize the RHS. In fact, if I choose any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then choosing $x = y$ will infimize RHS. So $u_t(x)$ just "tracks $u(y)$ with the vertex of an absolute value graph."

That doesn't seem useful for a proof for lower semicontinuity. Loosely speaking, how should I think of these functions $u_t(x)$?

Comment: No!  If $t=\frac12$ say, then $u_t(1)=\frac7{16}$ by using the point $y=\frac14$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, your calculation is incorrect for certain values of $t$. If $t$ is large enough, then yes, you will have $y=x=1$, but when $t$ gets smaller you will need to choose a different $y$ to attain the infimum. When $u(x) = x^2$, and you want to calculate $u_t(x),$ note that $$u_t(x) = \inf_{y} \{ y^2 + t \lvert y-x\rvert\}.$$ You are minimizing $$f_t(y,x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} y^2 + ty - tx, & y < x, \\ y^2 - ty + tx, & y > x. \end{matrix}\right.$$ You need to check the points where $\partial_y f_t(y,1) = 0$ or the derivative is undefined; the potential points you need to check are, $y=t/2, y= -t/2$ or $y = x$ (though the first two points are only viable in certain cases).

Indeed, as you have it defined, you will find that $u_t(x)$ is Lipschitz with constant $L = t$. In general, if $u$ is smooth, you will find that $u_t(x) = u(x)$ at places where $\lvert u'(x)\rvert  \le t$; otherwise, in regions where $\lvert u'(x) \rvert > t$, then $u_t(x)$ will essentially be linear with slope $t$, and it will be increasing or decreasing depending on the sign of $u'(x)$.

Going back to your example of $u(x) = x^2$, I have included four pictures to help you visualize this. The pictures are plotted for $x \in [-5,5]$. In each image, $u(x) = x^2$ is plotted in black and $u_t(x)$ is plotted in dotted red. Note that $\lvert u'(x)\rvert \le 10$ on this interval, thus when $t = 10$, we will have $u_t(x) \equiv u(x)$ on the interval. For lower values of $t$, $u_t(x) = u(x)$ for  $x\in [-t/2,t/2]$ but outside that interval, $u_t(x)$ is essentially linear with slope of magnitude $t$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Why isn't the definition of $f_t(y,x)$:
$$f_t(y,x) = \left\{\begin{matrix} y^2 + ty - tx, & -x \leq y \leq x, \\ y^2 - ty + tx, & y \in \mathbb{R}-[-x,x]. \end{matrix}\right.$$
When I graph these functions, they only have one "kink" -- so this can't be correct. But from the definition of absolute value, this was my guess.

Comment: 2. The discussion about what values $u_t(x)$ will take in regions where $|u'(x)|\leq t$ and $|u'(x)|>t$ are great. I'm getting mixed up working an example. For instance: $t = 1$ at $x = 1/2$ and $x = 3/2$. I suspect this is related to my confusion above.

Comment: 3. Is there a way to see $u_t(x)$ behaves in this manner (ie on $|u'(x)|\leq t$ it will take values of $u(x)$ and $|u'(x)|>t$ on a straight line below $u(x)$)? I can sort of see it from the definition: indeed if we fix $y$ then $f(y)+td(x,y)$ is a "absolute value graph", centered at $f(y)$ with slope $t$. However, we need to fix $x$ and vary $y$ -- so I became confused about how to think about this function.

Comment: okay I've figured out 1 and 2 after plotting them myself (thanks for the suggestion!). My functions $u_t(x)$ look different from yours though. In the next link I post an image and some code (matlab -- or octave will probably work). Also, how someone would guess this function (question 3) is still confusing to me.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oIZ857l -- in the picture, $u_t(x)$ is the weird multicolor line, with $t = 2$

Comment: I will ask the third question as a separate question